# Query inside a PostgreSQL function does not recognize its parameters

Tags: string, postgresql, runtime-error, plpgsql

I have a function where I want to generate a dynamic query via a character varying variable, I do (for example):

```
my_var character varying := 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.column = param_name';
```

And when I run my function and reaches instruction:

```
EXECUTE my_var INTO result_var;
```

I get the error

> ERROR:  column «param_name» does not exist

Note: I've repeatedly checked that `param_name` in the query matches with the parameter's name

Comment: You need to look at [Dynamic Query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Answer (score 2):

Use a placeholder then pass the actual parameter value with the `USING` clause:

```
declare
  my_var text := 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.column = $1';
  my_parameter int := 42;
  result_var int;
begin
  execute my_var 
    using my_parameter;
```

However your example does indicate the need for `execute` dynamic SQL) at all. You could easily remove it completely:

```
SELECT * 
  into result_var
FROM table 
WHERE table.column = my_parameter;
```

Comment: Thx very much, it worked. The code that I placed was just an expample of my problem. The real query is pretty big and I have to add conditions depending on some other parameters, it would have been very long to explain and read